# iOS 10: UIAlertController only showing one action

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertController:

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"Options"
                                          message:@""
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *start = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"Start"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {

                                 [self DisplayAlert:@"" textval:@"You are about to start. Would you like to continue?"];
                                 [actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                             }];
        UIAlertAction *idle = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"Idle"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {

                                 [self DisplayAlert:@"" textval:@"You are about to idle. Would you like to continue?"];
                                 [actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                             }];
        UIAlertAction *stop = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"Stop"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {

                                 [self DisplayAlert:@"" textval:@"You are about to stop. Would you like to continue?"];
                                 [actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                             }];
        UIAlertAction *enable = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Enable"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {

                                   [self DisplayAlert:@"" textval:@"You are about to enable. Would you like to continue?"];
                                   [actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                               }];

        UIAlertAction *disable = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Disable"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {

                                   [self DisplayAlert:@"" textval:@"You are about to disable. Would you like to continue?"];
                                   [actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                               }];

        UIAlertAction *clear = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Clear"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {

                                   [self DisplayAlert:@"" textval:@"You are about to clear. Would you like to continue?"];
                                   [actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                               }];
        UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                                 [actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                             }];


        [actionSheet addAction:start];
        [actionSheet addAction:idle];
        [actionSheet addAction:stop];
        [actionSheet addAction:enable];
        [actionSheet addAction:disable];
        [actionSheet addAction:clear];
        [actionSheet addAction:cancel];
        [actionSheet setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
        [actionSheet.view setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [actionSheet popoverPresentationController];
        popPresenter.barButtonItem = wellControlItem;
        [appDelegate.splitViewController presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Why is only one of these actions showing when the menu is displayed on an iPad?  I tested this on a 10.1 iPad sim and device (not working on either), as well as a 10.1 iPhone 7 sim and device (working on all iPhones).

This has been working since I fixed it after iOS 8 was released (setTintColor was added).  Debugging this is showing "7 actions" added, so I'm not sure where to go from here for the UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet, which is the desired display option.  **UIAlertControllerStyleAlert shows all 7 but I like the old UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet look.**

Comment: Unrelated but do not attempt to dismiss the action sheet from any of the action sheet's actions. It will automatically be dismissed when a button it tapped.

Comment: I have a somewhat similar issue in that only my top action will display when running on the simulator, but all actions display when running on the device. I'm not attempting to change tint color or any aspect of the UIAlertController, and the display mode is ActionSheet. Is this a bug in the simulators? They all exhibit the same problem.

Comment: @RonB. I just went with UIAlertControllerStyleAlert and called it a day.  My new version is already in the store since the ActionSheet popup feature has been buggy since iOS 8..why fight it.  Hey, would you mind upvoting this question if you think it's valid?  Someone downvoted a legitimate question and it was kind of annoying.  when an question has negative votes, it takes away from possibly helping another person at quick glance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under iOS 10, showing a `UIAlertController` with a style of "ActionSheet" doesn't work properly if you attempt to set the alert controller view's `tintColor`. I ran into this issue when updating my app for iOS 10. I filed a bug report with Apple.

So your primary issue will be solved by not calling:

```
[actionSheet.view setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

under iOS 10.

Unrelated to this problem, your code is mistakenly attempting to dismiss the alert controller from inside the various alert actions. Do not do this. The alert will be dismissed automatically. You need to remove all of your calls to:

```
[actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Note that this bug only appears if you have more than 5 UIAlertActions in the UIAlertController.  With 5 or less, everything is fine.

Comment: Also, it is still possible to set the tintColor from inside the presentViewController's completionHandler. Setting tint color from inside the completion handler works fine (it does not trip over the same iOS 10 bug), although there may be a brief flash where the original tint color shows before it is changed.

Comment: This occurred when I had 6 actions in the UIAlertController.  It was hard to find the reason, so I just wanted to write "6 actions" for future searchers.  Thanks!